# AlertDialog within PopupWindow's OnClickListener - allowed?

Tags: android

I need to have an `AlertDialog` appear when a certain button on a `PopupWindow` is clicked. In order to call `AlertDialog.Builder()` I need a `context`. If I try using "`this`" then I get an error "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from new View.OnClickListener(){} to Context`". There are several other kinds of context I know of like `getBaseContext()` but when I try those instead the program crashes. I'm not sure which type I should use, and am worried whether fundamentally the OS is trying to tell me that having an `alertdialog` within a `pupupwindow` is a no-no.

Comment: Use your `MyActivityName.this` instead. Otherwise you're giving it your `onClickListener` (which I'm assuming is anonymous) which doesn't implement `Context` (Using your activity name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the parent activity as the context Mick. That will be the appropriate context for the dialog.

Comment: But yes I agree, pop-ups spawning further pop-ups is an annoying UI leading to sub-optimal UX.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks. Will give tick as soon as system allows. FYI, I know this is a rather irregular UI sequence, but it is for rather exceptional circumstances - I'm not using it lightly.